# Wordpress admin menu keeps folding

Tags: wordpress, menu, admin

Some time ago, wordpress admin menu got folded and since this point I am unable to keep it opened, I need to press on the small triangle to open it.

I tried to hit `wp-admin/index.php?unfoldmenu=1` and it did not help.
It is not a browser cookie/cache issue since I have opened the admin from a totally new pc and it's still happening.

Maybe there is a JavaScript hook for that? (Version 3.5.1)

Comment: Check if there are any javascript errors.
Which browser are you using?

Comment: @PrathameshGharat there are no JS ERRORS, I am using chrome Version 26.0.1410.43 m but basically I have tried from several browsers and PC's, thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

i ended up writing a custom script in my theme functions.php.
its a temp solution, but works for now.

```
function make_menu_unfolded() {
    print '<script>jQuery(document).ready(function(){jQuery("body").removeClass("folded")})</script>';
}

add_filter('admin_head', 'make_menu_unfolded');
```

Answer (score 4):

This is the right method to solve this bug:

```
SELECT * FROM wp_usermeta WHERE meta_value LIKE '%mfold%';

+----------+---------+------------------+------------+
| umeta_id | user_id | meta_key         | meta_value |
+----------+---------+------------------+------------+
|     1152 |       4 | wp_user-settings | mfold=f    |
+----------+---------+------------------+------------+
```

Just need to delete this line and clear you browser cache/cookies.

```
DELETE FROM wp_usermeta WHERE umeta_id = 1152;
```

Please make sure you are not deleting anything else.

Thanks 
Cristian Trif

Answer (score 0):

I suggest updating your wordpress. The drop down feature has been upgraded a few versions back. What version are you on? the newest is 3.5.1

Comment: yup, seems they removed the collapse all feature since version 3.3
Read more about it here.
http://wordpress.org/support/topic/admin-menu-doesnt-expandcollapse-in-33-beta-1-why